# Interrupt the animation and jump to a specific keyframes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a animation like this

```
div {
    position: relative;

    -webkit-animation: bouger 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bouger {

    0%       { left: 0%;   } 
    50%      { left: 50%;   } 
    100%     { left: 100%;   }

}
```

How can i interrupt the animation and go to the keyframes 50% (`left: 50%;`) after a click like that

```
<div>CC</div>
<input type="button" value="Go to 50%" />
```

here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SvdUN/) and i want that the animation  continues after.

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery:

this will stop the animation and move the div to left 50%.

```
$("input").click(function() {
    $("div").css({
        '-webkit-animation' : 'none',
        'left' :  '50%'
    })
})
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SvdUN/1/)

or you can move it to left 50% and continue the animation from there by defining a new @-webkit-keyframes and run it by adding a class to your div. like so:

```
div.two {
    left:50%;
    -webkit-animation: bouger2 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bouger2 {
    0%      { left: 50%;   } 
    100%     { left: 100%;   }
}
```

code below is using toggleClass which will go back and forth from bouger and bouger2, but you can change it to 'addClass' if u wish:

```
$("input").click(function() {
    $("div").toggleClass('two')
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SvdUN/3/

Comment: but i want that the animation continues after that.

Comment: But when i have many buttons to click for example : 5 it will be complicated to create 5 new other annimation